# Cannot resolve maven dependency: Failure to find javax.persistence:ejb:jar:3.0-public-draft-20060327

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm trying to resurrect an **old** project. I wanted to use Maven to manage dependencies/build/etc., and I got pretty far, but now I'm running into an error that I can't seem to resolve, and that I can't seem to find anything about:

> Failed to execute goal on project scanit: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.cbojar:scanit:jar:0.2: Could not find artifact javax.persistence:ejb:jar:3.0-public-draft-20060327 in maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

It wants to download a `ejb-3.0-public-draft-20060327.jar` file, but that file [does not exist in the repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/ejb/3.0-public-draft-20060327/).

I'm relatively new to maven, and I wanted to use this as practice, but I have now painted myself into a corner. Below is my `pom.xml` file.

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.cbojar</groupId>
    <artifactId>scanit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/bin/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/bin/test</testOutputDirectory>
        <directory>${basedir}/bin</directory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>net.cbojar.scanit.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2</id>
            <name>Central Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <!--These are needed for Swing/Netbeans -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.netbeans.maven2</id>
            <name>Netbeans Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- TODO: Update to JUnit 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE701</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1beta9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
            <version>r938</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't see any dependency as `ejb-3.0-public-draft-20060327` in your pom.

Comment: @dazito There isn't one, but I'm thinking it's a transitive dependency maybe?

Comment: @dazito I just tested and it is a transitive dependency of `hibernate-annotations:3.1beta9`

Comment: I recommend you to use the most up to date version of each dependency and try again. A google search for that dependency shows up as from 2006. On a side note, you have `asm` repeated twice in your pom.

Comment: @dazito Because it's an old code base (from around 2007), would using the most up-to-date versions break things (API changes and whatnot)?

Comment: @cbojar There are at least 3 different versions of Hibernate in conflict in your pom. What is the old project actual dependency on Hibernate? You should stick with this one.

Comment: @Tunaki That didn't click in my head until you said that, but those are the actual original dependencies for the app, down to the version number. In some ways, it's amazing the code could even run.

Comment: @cbojar If the old code doesn't depend on `ejb-3.0-public-draft-20060327`, you could try to exclude it in the pom and see what happens.

Comment: @Tunaki That ended up being the right answer. If you want to write it up, I'll accept it, or if you'd rather I can just write it up.

Comment: @cbojar I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are converting to Maven an existing project, you should respect the original dependencies. That means adding as a Maven dependency the exact same version of the original dependencies and excluding unused transitive dependency (since the original project doesn't need it and it works correctly then we can safely exclude them from the pom).

It turns out that `javax.persistence:ejb:jar:3.0-public-draft-20060327` is a transitive dependency of `org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.1beta9`. If the original project doesn't need it, you can exclude it from the pom like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.1beta9</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        <exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1beta9</version>
</dependency>
```

And use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

That is the dependency causing you that problem. It is from 2006. I also recommend you to update your dependencies version to the most up to date.

**EDIT**

As such an upgrade may break your code, and without further details, you should probably stick with a version closer to the one you are trying to use.

[Check here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations) for all hibernate-annotations versions available in maven repo.

Comment: Updating Hibernate may not be a viable solution: it can break the existing code.

Comment: That may be true but without more details I don't see a better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Might be better to go with a hibernate final version closer to 3.1

Comment: I've just edited my answer stating that. Still, the closest *final* to 3.1 is 3.5 from 2010.

Comment: @dazito This made the error go away, but unfortunately it led to API incompatibilities. It's still a good answer and may help others, so +1, but it didn't exactly solve the problem completely. Thanks for your help, though, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need this dependecy declaration inside your project pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-3.0-public-draft</artifactId>
        <version>20050627</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't make a difference when I tried it. The trouble was with a transitive dependency, so adding another one didn't satisfy it.